# The code is ignoring some lines and I don't know why

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

The code is a video editor and it opens and app drags the file in and edits the resolution but when it clicks on the text box it doesn't remove any characters. The ignored code is showed by:

```
#ignored\/
#ignored/\
```

```
try:
    import pyautogui, time, subprocess
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

    kb = Controller()       
    
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE=False
    TTCF = open("C:/Users/admin/Documents/python/Vids/Vid.txt", "rt")
    TTC = int(TTCF.read())+1
    VidName = "Vid "+str(TTC)
    TTCF.close()
    time.sleep(3)

    TTCF = open("Vids\VidCount.txt", "w")
    TTCF.write(str(TTC))
    TTCF.close()

    #macro start
    pyautogui.click(2559, 1439)
    pyautogui.click(117, 430, clicks=2, interval=0.25)
    time.sleep(7)
    pyautogui.click(1506, 1100)
    kb.type(TikTokName)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(1410, 742)
    subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select ,"C:\Users\admin\Documents\python\Vids\Vid.mp4"')
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.moveTo(1255, 0)
    pyautogui.dragTo(1910, 345, 0.5)
    pyautogui.moveTo(1660, 470)
    pyautogui.dragTo(140, 265, 0.5)


    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.click(x=77, y=180, button="right")
    time.sleep(0.01)
    pyautogui.click(x=172, y=200)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    pyautogui.click(x=1049, y=783)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    pyautogui.click(x=1227, y=616)
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(x=1277, y=676)
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(x=1347, y=676)
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(x=1276, y=779)
    time.sleep(2)
    #ignored\/
    kb.press(Key.backspace)
    time.sleep(1)
    kb.release(Key.backspace)
    time.sleep(2)
    kb.type("1080")
    #ignored/\
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.click(x=1256, y=940)
    time.sleep(3)
    #ignored\/
    kb.press(Key.backspace)
    time.sleep(1)
    kb.release(Key.backspace)
    time.sleep(3)
    kb.type("1920")
    #ignored /\
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(x=1434, y=885)

except Exception as e:
    input(e)
```

it doesn't give me any errors it just ignores it, and it works when i remove the rest of the code.

Comment: `pyautogui.click(x=1276, y=779)` Where, exactly, does that place the mouse cursor?  If it's at the _start_ of a text field, pressing backspace won't have any effect.

Comment: @JohnGordon it places it at the end of the text box

Comment: @JohnGordon i tested it in notepad too, it also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes pyautogui can be slow so I think that it is going to be slow, I would like add more time to the thing after it like maybe 7 seconds. Unless this needs to be really fast. If so, use something like pynput.

Comment: Instead of an answer, this could be posted as a comment.